# I want to insert column in cross-tabulation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I have Pandas cross-tabulation object.

```
| Age Category | A | B  | C  | D |
|--------------|---|----|----|---|
| 21-26        | 2 | 2  | 4  | 1 |
| 26-31        | 7 | 11 | 12 | 5 |
| 31-36        | 3 | 5  | 5  | 2 |
| 36-41        | 2 | 4  | 1  | 7 |
| 41-46        | 0 | 1  | 3  | 2 |
| 46-51        | 0 | 0  | 2  | 3 |
| Above 51     | 0 | 3  | 0  | 6 |
```

If I am doing `age.dtypes` this is giving me output

```
Age Category
A int64
B int64
C int64
D int64 
dtype: object
```

But I want **Age Category** should also be `object`. If it need to insert one more column for that that would be fine. So that the `age.dtypes` should show something like this

```
Age Category
Age Category  object
A             int64
B             int64
C             int64
D             int64 
dtype: object
```

Thank you for your time and consideration

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for convert index to column and then if necessary `rename_axis`:

```
age = age.reset_index().rename_axis(columns='Age Category')
print (age.dtypes)
Age Category
Age Category    object
A                int64
B                int64
C                int64
D                int64
dtype: object
```

EDIT:

If columns names are categoricals use [`CategoricalIndex.add_categories`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.CategoricalIndex.add_categories.html) before:

```
age.columns = age.columns.add_categories(['Age Category'])
age = age.reset_index().rename_axis(columns='Age Category')

print (age.dtypes)
Age Category
Age Category    object
A                int64
B                int64
C                int64
D                int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: I am getting `TypeError: cannot insert an item into a CategoricalIndex that is not already an existing category`

Comment: Now, I am getting `ValueError: new categories must not include old categories: {'Age Category'}`

Comment: @MaqsudInamdar - there is no use `age.columns = age.columns.add_categories(['Age Category'])` twice?

Comment: @jezrael I have a question. You probably use `pd.read_clipboard()` to copy the table of OP. How do you get rid of those symbols like `-` and `|` in the table? Do you remove them manually or there is some better ways with `pandas`?

Comment: @MykolaZotko - A bit shame, but replacing manually in notepad... :(

Comment: @jezrael Thank you. I will try to make a question on this issue. :)

Comment: @MykolaZotko But dinner time for me now, so maybe 30 minutes offline

Comment: @jezrael Is it possible to copy the index of column and then insert it using `.insert()` function in python.

Comment: @MaqsudInamdar - yes, use `df.insert(1, 'Age Category', df.index)`

Comment: @jezrael Its not working. Is it possible to copy the elements of Categorical Index and then create new column.

Comment: @MaqsudInamdar - You have to do it like `age.columns = age.columns.add_categories(['Age Category'])
age.insert(1, 'Age Category', age.index)
age = age.rename_axis(columns='Age Category')`

Comment: @jezrael, I am getting `ValueError: new categories must not include old categories: {'age_category'}`

Comment: @MaqsudInamdar - If remove `age.columns = age.columns.add_categories(['Age Category'])` not working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203749/discussion-between-maqsud-inamdar-and-jezrael).